# Is there a more efficient way to order an array based on how many associations each record has?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a model `Item` that has_many of another model `Vote`. I have a method for `Item` called `vote_count`:

```
def vote_count
  self.votes.count
end
```

and I'm printing a list of the 10 Items with the most Votes:

```
Item.all.sort_by(&:vote_count).reverse.first(10)
```

This method works, but it's fairly slow, because the server has to load every single Vote in the database. Does anyone know of a more efficient way to do this?

I can't just create a column that is increased by 1 every time a Vote is created, because Votes are soft-deleted after 7 days with a default_scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you also express the logic of the soft delete in SQL?

The best thing here would be to use an ORDER BY in the database, whereby you GROUP BY ITEMS.ID and order by a SQL aggregate function ...

```
order("sum(case when vote.created_at >= ... then 1 else 0 end)")
```

Don't know MySQL syntax, but it can probably do something like this, and it would be much faster than a Rails method.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to do the work of sorting and limiting the records in the database, and then loading the final 10 results into rails after that. You might try something like this:

```
Item.order('vote_count desc').limit(10)
```

You might need to change 'desc' to 'asc' if I've incorrectly guessed what the reverse order should be.